# Can you use constructors as conditions without calling them

Tags: c#, constructor, conditional-statements

I understand that the this title may be a bit ambiguous, but I wasn't sure how else to try and explain what I am trying to do.

I have a huge number of vectors that I am trying to classify into cells.  I use a constructor to classify the vectors in groups of 4.  Should this code work, even though I never use the variable "cell", but do use "Cells"?

```
public class assignCells
{

    public static List<List<Vector3>> Cells = new List<List<Vector3>>();

    public assignCells(Vector3 bottom, Vector3 top, Vector3 right, Vector3 left)
    {
        if (top.x == bottom.x + 20.0 && right.z == left.z + 50.0)
        {
            Cells.Add(new List<Vector3> { bottom, top, right, left });
        }
    }
}  

public void gC()
{
    List<Vector3> old = new List<Vector3>();

    List<int> rnL = new List<int>();

    for (int i = 0; i < xsize * zsize; i++)
    {

        List<Vector3> tC = assignCells.Cells[rn];
        List<int> rCg = new List<int>
        {
            rn + 1,
            rn + 201,
            rn - 1,
            rn - 201
        };
        int rCp = rc.Next(1, 5);
        int oC = rCg[rCp];
        List<Vector3> nC = assignCells.Cells[oC];

        if (nC == null)
        {
            if(old.Contains(tC[1]) || old.Contains(tC[2]) || old.Contains(tC[3]) || old.Contains(tC[4])){
                rnL[i--] = rn;
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                i--;
            }

        }
        if(tC[1] == nC[2])
        {
            tC.RemoveAt(1);
            Instantiate(Wall, tC[2], Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0));
            Instantiate(Wall, tC[3], Quaternion.Euler(90, 0, 0));
            Instantiate(Wall, tC[4], Quaternion.Euler(90, 0, 0));
            assignCells.Cells.Insert(rn, old);
            assignCells.Cells.RemoveAt(rn);
        }
        if (tC[3] == nC[4])
        {
            tC.RemoveAt(3);
            Instantiate(Wall, tC[1], Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0));
            Instantiate(Wall, tC[2], Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0));
            Instantiate(Wall, tC[4], Quaternion.Euler(90, 0, 0));
            assignCells.Cells.Insert(rn, old);
            assignCells.Cells.RemoveAt(rn);
        }
        if (tC[2] == nC[1])
        {
            tC.RemoveAt(2);
            Instantiate(Wall, tC[1], Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0));
            Instantiate(Wall, tC[3], Quaternion.Euler(90, 0, 0));
            Instantiate(Wall, tC[4], Quaternion.Euler(90, 0, 0));
            assignCells.Cells.Insert(rn, old);
            assignCells.Cells.RemoveAt(rn);
        }
        if (tC[4] == nC[3])
        {
            tC.RemoveAt(4);
            Instantiate(Wall, tC[1], Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0));
            Instantiate(Wall, tC[2], Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0));
            Instantiate(Wall, tC[3], Quaternion.Euler(90, 0, 0));
            assignCells.Cells.Insert(rn, old);
            assignCells.Cells.RemoveAt(rn);
        }
        rnL.Add(rn);
        rn = oC;

    }
}


void CreateW()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < zsize * xsize; i++)
    {
        int n = i;
        int nn = 50 * n;
        int nn2 = 20 * n;
        mazeNumH.Add(new Vector3(-5000 + nn, 0, -5000 + nn2));
        mazeNumV.Add(new Vector3(-5000 + nn2, 0, -5000 + nn));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < zsize * xsize; i++)
    {
        assignCells cell = new assignCells(mazeNumH[i], mazeNumH[i + zsize], mazeNumV[i], mazeNumV[i + 1]);
    }
    gC();
}
```

Comment: What does a vector passed to the constructor has anything to do with another instance? You'll hit yourself on the head when you realize this will make problems. Don't make anything static when it is bound to an instance.

Comment: If you want it to be static all the way, don't use contructors, use static method instead. If you don't want to use static. Just don't use a constructor but just a method that fills the `Cells` field.

Comment: Or just remove the `assignCells cell = `, but I don't like the approach of misusing the way you use a constructor to fill static fields.

Comment: "If you want it to be static all the way, don't use contructors, use static method instead. If you don't want to use static. Just don't use a constructor but just a method that fills the Cells field" thank you for the help, I don't know what I was thinking with my attempt at this.

Comment: Is it some kind of [BSP tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_space_partitioning)?

Comment: Yes.  I am having a hard time getting it to actually perform it's job, though